# MATLAB - Finding a period of a function (Position vs time graph)

Tags: matlab

I'm a new Matlab user and I'm currently having trouble in finding the period for my graph function. I understand that for this case, the period can be calculated by multiplying the distance(x-comp) of the min point and max point by 2. Can someone give me instructions? Thank you.

code:

```
clc, clear
x=0:2:200;
y=(2*sind(3.2*x))+(1.8*cosd(3.2*x));
plot(x,y)
xlabel('Time(Seconds)');
ylabel('Location(Inches)');
title('Object Location');
grid on;
disp(['Amplitude = ', num2str(max(y)-min(y))]);
```

Comment: What do you want "instructions" for? You already give a solution: *multiplying the distance(x-comp) of the min point and max point by 2*. So just do that and your problem is solved right?

Answer (score 1):

Note: Just noticed the graphs are plotted in seconds. Concepts still apply.

I prefer to evaluate the period by finding the distance between the two maximums, especially when the behaviour of the signal is known. The function `islocalmax()` creates a logical array that is true "1" when a local maximum is found and false "0" otherwise. The function `find` can be used to find which indices that meet a condition in this cause being true "1" → and a local maximum. Lastly, is evaluating the corresponding x values to the local maximums and finding the difference between them. For more precision changing the interval value for x will result in a more accurate calculation.

```
clc, clear
x=0:2:200;
y=(2*sind(3.2*x))+(1.8*cosd(3.2*x));
plot(x,y)
xlabel('Time(Seconds)');
ylabel('Location(Inches)');
title('Object Location');
grid on;
disp(['Amplitude = ', num2str(max(y)-min(y))]);

%Finding where the local maximas are located%
Local_Maximas = islocalmax(y);
%Evaluating which indicies of signal y are a local maxima%
Indicies = find(Local_Maximas == 1);
%Evaluating the x displacement between the two local maxima%
Period_In_Degrees = x(1,Indicies(1,2)) - x(1,Indicies(1,1));

Period_In_Degrees

%Plotting maximum locations%
Maximum = max(y);
X_Point_2 = x(1,Indicies(1,1));
X_Point_1 = x(1,Indicies(1,2));
hold on
plot(X_Point_1,Maximum,'o');
plot(X_Point_2,Maximum,'o');
```

**Mathematically:**

The fundamental frequency can be found by taking the **Greatest Common Divisor (GCD)** and the **Least Common Multiple (LCM)** of the frequency components. The period can be found after finding the fundamental frequency by taking reciprocal.

In this case, the frequency components come from the two sinusoids:

sind(3.2x) → 3.2 times for every 360° → **112.5° per period.**

cosd(3.2x) → 3.2 times for every 360° → **112.5° per period.**

Where x the axis plotted in degrees.

The two frequencies are f1 = 3.2 and f2 = 3.2
or w1 = 3.2×2π radians and w2 = 3.2×2π radians.

Since the two periods and frequencies of the components are the same the period is 112.5°.

[image: Fundamantal Period/Frequency]